# Displaying random product in a related product table of 5

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am  creating a row of "product related table of x5" and using MYSQLcode RAND to generate RANDOM products and a exception clause using id!='$id' - where id is existing product that is being viewed currently.

However the problem is that all the product images generated were all of the same similar product image. 
Can anyone shed some light on this?

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubmF0.jpg) for better reference:

```
include "MyOnlineStore/storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql2          = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bag WHERE id!='$id'ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 5");
$productCount2 = mysql_num_rows($sql2); // count the output amount
if ($productCount2 > 0) {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>    
    <?php
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        $idrelated    = $row2["id"];
        $imagerelated = $row2["image"];
        $titlerelated = $row2["title"];
    }
} else {
    echo "That item does not exist.";
    exit();
}
mysql_close();
```

HTML

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what is the type of your id column . int or varchar or something else

Comment: @raheelshan its int(50)

Comment: _"all of the same similar product image"_ happens because you construct the relevant tags outside (i.e. _after_) your loop.

Comment: Is there a way not to use a loop ?

Comment: off topic, but I note that your code is using several obsolete or deprecated techniques. You should consider updating it. (hints: the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated; you shoul always use `<?php` rather than just `<?`; you should use CSS to specify a border rather than the HTML `border="1"` attribute; likewise for height/width; you should avoid using `<table>` tags if the data isn't actually a table, use `<div>` elements instead (it's arguable in this case but I'd say it's not a table).

Comment: @Spudley Thank you for pointing out! I will take note it. New here :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be something like this

```
include "MyOnlineStore/storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql2          = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bag WHERE id!='$id'ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 5");
$productCount2 = mysql_num_rows($sql2); // count the output amount
if ($productCount2 > 0) {
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>    
    <?php
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        $idrelated    = $row2["id"];
        $imagerelated = $row2["image"];
        $titlerelated = $row2["title"];
        ?>
            <td>
                <a href="http://example.net/product.php?id=<?php echo $idrelated; ?>">
                    <img src="admin/product/uploaded_files/<?php echo $imagerelated; ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $titlerelated; ?>" /> 
                </a>
            </td>
        <?php
    }
?>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 1000 points to gryffindor!!! You even shortened my code. GREAT! once again, thank you! appreciated much! Lastly, thanks to those who offered help as well!

Comment: You can also give some extra points by clicking on up arrow near check sign if you think it is useful for you

Comment: would be willing to! however "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from your code, the following variables:

```
$idrelated, $imagerelated, $titlerelated
```

remains unchanged after leaving the loop. So in each line you refer to the same variable and value.

If you want to keep use some array to keep all five values:

```
<?php 
$index = 0;
while (...) { 
   $relatedA[$index] = ...;
   $relatedB[$index] = ...;
   $relatedC[$index] = ...;
   $index++;
}
?>
...

<?php echo $relatedA[0]; ?>
<?php echo $relatedA[1]; ?>
...
<?php echo $relatedA[4]; ?>
```

The last you can put in the loop again to avoid redundant code.

#### UPDATE

Try to resist the temptation of putting echoes into the first loop where you fetch values - as it could result in hard to maintenance spaghetti-style code (unfortunately quite commonly seen in many php sources).